# Modernize Javascript code for a dropdown menu animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, drop-down-menu

In a post related to another questiona a user suggested me to modernize the js code. Use specifically `x.classList.includes()`, `x.classList.add()`, and `x.classList.remove()`.

So I tried to follow the suggestion and did what you see below. The dropdown menu works well, the only doubt that remains is how to implement `x.classList.includes()` ? Although everything works as it should I would like to understand if I can improve the code further.

Also I wanted to understand what is the difference between the old and new code? Are there any changes in performance, functionality or anything else? Sorry but I'm new, I'm trying to learn and stack is very useful.

Also I wanted to ask, how can I add an icon to the button that changes when the menu is open or closed ? Here you find the question about the icon, if you can help me I would appreciate it. [How to add animate icon menu dropdown open / closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72223397/how-to-add-animate-icon-menu-dropdown-open-closed/72225512#72225512)

Apologize for bad English, I'm not doing very well.

Project: https://jsfiddle.net/Snorlax93x/v0c39heo/2/

**Old Js code**

```
var menu = document.querySelector(".user_menu_button");
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Demo");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else { 
    x.className += " w3-hide";
    setTimeout(function(){
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
      x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-hide", "");
      
    }, 100)
  }
}
```

**New Js Code**

```
var menu = document.querySelector(".user_menu_button");
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Demo");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.classList.add ("w3-show");
  
  } else { 
    x.classList.add("w3-hide");

    setTimeout(function(){
     x.classList.remove("w3-show");
     x.classList.remove("w3-hide");  
    },100)
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {` becomes `if (!x.classList.includes("w3-show")) {`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I've already tried and it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: that should work. notice the presence of the exclamation mark, which negates the condition (if classlist of element x not includes "w3-show")

Comment: @GrafiCode I tried again by copying the code from your comment and the menu won't open.

Comment: Try... https://jsfiddle.net/Snorlax93x/v0c39heo/2/

Comment: ah sorry, it's "contains". Try this: `if (!x.classList.contains("w3-show")) {`

Comment: It works fine now, thanks. If I may ask, what changes between the old one and the new one Js I posted in the question? Why should I get this new one rather than the old one ?

Comment: Consider your old code: `if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1)` for instance, it fails if element has a similar class, like "w3-showing". New code doesn't make confusion.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList